# Login banned on Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am implementing realtime multiplayer game using Google Play Game Services. I am experiencing weird issues. My Google Account I am using for login gets randomly "banned" and is unable to communicate with Google servers for approx. 30-40 minutes. After that, everything is working well again. In the meantime I can use other accounts.

The response error I get from LogCat is this:

```
Unexpected response code 403 for
https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/102515671693140579145
Access Not Configured
Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

This message is very misleading since everything is set up well. It works most of the time.

I have tried publishing the game and using test as well as non-test accounts. All of them get banned at some point.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Google likes to ban accounts which connect to often. It's the same with play store purchases. Is that a problem which occurs because you login a lot in your application or because you login a lot while testing?

Comment: @paxdiablo Google encourages devs to ask questions about Play Game Services here at SO

Comment: @schlingel I am not logging in too often I think. This is a pain when developing the game. What are the test-acounts for then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior will occur if:

Current user is connected into any room and:

the app is restarted such that it tries to login to Google Services without having gone through the disconnect portion as required by Google Play Services.

I found this happened to me quite regularly (unfortunately for me) as I was figuring out how to pass messages between my Android code and LibGDX code side (my app would just Lock up due to synchronization issues). I also setup some test accounts that I could "cycle" through to avoid being completely locked out of logging in. However, I found out that if I used Task Manager to Kill the process before restarting the app, 90+ percent of the time, I could continue to use the same account.

If you are updating your code, and load to the device while you are in a Room, this will also earn you the server wrath for approximately 30 minutes for that account.

In short, to keep your account viable:

1) ensure you LeaveRoom prior to updating your code (I have found logging out of PS is not required)

2) If your app locks up... Killing the process via Task Manager (I use Samsung devices) will most likely let your account continue (you can see in the logcat where it calls the disconnect when you do that) when you start up the app again.